# LogParser2.2 and Logs on load-balanced servers

Tags: iis, c#-4.0, load-balancing, logging, logparser

I need to run a report that shows all authenticated users. The query itself seems to be pretty easy. My problem is that I have to gather data from 2 sets of logs (we run our web application in a load balanced set up). Has anyone have to deal with a similiar task?

Answer (score 1):

If you can access both logs via one machine then your FROM clause can certainly include both log directory paths:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM \\server1\Logs\*ex*.log, \\server2\Logs\*ex*.log
```

In every environment where I've had to parse logs we've had processes in place to pull logs down to a single server, and then we do any parsing on that machine (and it serves as a backup).